# Search for character sequence containing any four consecutive numbers in Python pandas

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

I am trying to identify rows for which the column `col` contains the character sequence `JD-XXXX` in a pandas DataFrame. `XXXX` should be any sequence of four consecutive numbers.

How can I achieve this? So far I have

```
df[df['col'].str.contains('JD-', na=False)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for regular expressions:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col'])
df1.loc[0, 'col'] = "JD-1234" 
df1.loc[1, 'col'] = "JD-12344" 
df1.loc[2, 'col'] = "JD-12" 
df1.loc[3, 'col'] = "JD-1555" 
df1.loc[4, 'col'] = "JD-123" 
df1.loc[5, 'col'] = "JD-123456" 
df1.loc[6, 'col'] = "123456" 
df1.loc[7, 'col'] = "JD-" 
df1.loc[8, 'col'] = "JD-5656" 
print(df1)
df1[df1.col.str.contains('JD-\d{4}$', regex= True, na=False)]
```

This gives you:

```
 col
0    JD-1234
1   JD-12344
2      JD-12
3    JD-1555
4     JD-123
5  JD-123456
6     123456
7        JD-
8    JD-5656
col
0   JD-1234
3   JD-1555
8   JD-5656
```

This can be saved into a new column or as you wish. Only the rows beginning with `JD-` following with 4 digits will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a corresponding Regex pattern `r'JD-\d{4}'`